# How to make multiple API calls from multiple pages in single URL

Tags: python-3.x, url, grequests

So the title is a little confusing I guess..

I have a script that I've been writing that will display some random data and other non-essentials when I open my shell. I'm using grequests to make my API calls since I'm using more than one URL. For my weather data, I use WeatherUnderground's API since it will offer active alerts. The **alerts** and **conditions** data are on separate pages. What I can't figure out is how to insert the appropriate name in the grequests object when it is making requests. Here is the code that I have:

```
URLS = ['http://api.wunderground.com/api/'+api_id+'/conditions/q/autoip.json',
        'http://www.ourmanna.com/verses/api/get/?format=json',
        'http://quotes.rest/qod.json',
        'http://httpbin.org/ip']

requests = (grequests.get(url) for url in URLS)
responses = grequests.map(requests)
data = [response.json() for response in responses]

#json parsing from here
```

In the URL `'http://api.wunderground.com/api/'+api_id+'/conditions/q/autoip.json'` I need to make an API request to **conditions** and **alerts** to retrieve the data I need. How do I do this without rewriting a fourth URLS string?

I've tried

```
pages = ['conditions', 'alerts']
URL = ['http://api.wunderground.com/api/'+api_id+([p for p in pages])/q/autoip.json']
```

but, as I'm sure some of you more seasoned programmers know, threw and exception. So how can I iterate through these pages, or will I have to write out both complete URLS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was actually able to figure out how to call each individual page within the grequests object by using a simple **for** loop. Here is the the code that I used to produced the expected results:

```
import grequests

pages = ['conditions', 'alerts']
api_id = 'myapikeyhere' 

for p in pages:
    URLS = ['http://api.wunderground.com/api/'+api_id+'/'+p+'/q/autoip.json',
            'http://www.ourmanna.com/verses/api/get/?format=json',
            'http://quotes.rest/qod.json',
            'http://httpbin.org/ip']

    #create grequest object and retrieve results
    requests = (grequests.get(url) for url in URLS)
    responses = grequests.map(requests)
    data = [response.json() for response in responses]

    #json parsing from here
```

I'm still not sure why I couldn't figure this out before.

Documentation for the grequests library [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grequests)